# C#: How to ignore logs from Tesseract?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, tesseract

I have an API running on Docker Linux image, which uses [Tesseract wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) for reading text from images. Every time Tesseract is processing an image it logs a lot of warnings and communicates:

> | Estimating resolution as 682
>
> | Empty page!!
>
> | Estimating resolution as 682
>
> | Empty page!!
>
> | Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
>
> | Estimating resolution as 1408

One request invokes Tesseract up to 50 times, which causes logs to be a huge mess. To log information I need I use **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging**. I tried disabling the logging from Tesseract in *appsettings.json* like this:

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information", 
      "Tesseract": "Error"
    }
  },
```

as well as setting "Tesseract": "None" but none of it helped. I also tried looking it up in documentation of Tesseract, but didn't found anything. Is there any way to disable logs from Tesseract only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've found a little workaround to this. After initializing an instance of a Tesseract engine, to remove

> | Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.

I needed to set DPI manually for Engine:

```
_tesseractEngine.SetVariable("user_defined_dpi", "300");
```

And to remove "Empty page!!" either `debug_file` needs to be set for `NUL`,

```
_tesseractEngine.SetVariable("debug_file", "NUL");
```

Or `DefaultPageSegMode` needs to be set correctly.

```
_tesseractEngine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.SingleBlock;
```